# Log changes detected to domaincontext based on haschanges and getchanges

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework-4

I have a Silverlight application that is using Entity Framework 4. In the app, it is possible for the user to add/remove string representations of Active Directory group names into the configuration - changes are not saved in the backend until the 'save' button is clicked.

When 'save' is clicked, Entity Framework updates the backend with the changes to the DomainContext. This is working as expected. But I want to log the changes being made and send them out in an email each time before context.SubmitChanges() fires. What is the easiest way to log the changes? I already have code that I can reuse to email the changes to be logged.

I am looking at context.ADGroupRules.EntityContainer.GetChanges() and can see AddedEntities and RemovedEntities properties in there but I'm not sure how to 'get at' the highlighted string in the included snip in order to log it.

```
        if (command == "Save")
            {
                if (_context.HasChanges)
                {
                    var changeSet = _context.ADGroupRules.EntityContainer.GetChanges();

                 //log and email changes here

                    _context.SubmitChanges(OnSubmitCompleted, null);
                }
            }
```

[image: Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.

```
            if (command == "Save")
            {
               if (_context.HasChanges)
               {
                   var changeSet = _context.ADGroupRules.EntityContainer.GetChanges();
                   foreach (var entity in changeSet.AddedEntities.OfType<ADGroupRule>())
                   {
                       ADGroupRule rule = (ADGroupRule)entity;
                       Console.WriteLine(rule.ADGroupName);//simulate logging-emailing
                   }
```